# Angular UI Datepicker not closing after i select date or press close in IE9, works in chrome

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

any ideas why my datepicker is not closing in IE9 after i select a date?  close button not working either...

Code available on [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/#/yujR9GSGb9OS2k8C6yaU).

```
<div ng-app="arApp">

    <div ng-controller="AnnouncementRequestCtrl as vm">
        <legend>Your announcement request</legend>
        <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)"
            data-ng-animate="">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
        <div ng-show="showForm">
            <ng-form id="arform" name="arform" novalidate>

                <div class="form-group" >
                    <label class="control-label">
                        start date<div class="help-block error" ng-show="arform.sdate.$error.required">*</div></label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sdate" id="sdate" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="sdate"
                                is-open="opened1" min-date="minDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                                ng-required="true" close-text="Close" required ng-focus="vm.open($event,'opened1')" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.open($event,'opened1')">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <label class="control-label">
                        end date<div class="help-block error" ng-show="arform.edate.$error.required">*</div></label>
                    <p class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="edate" id="edate" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="edate"
                            is-open="opened2" min-date="sdate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
                            ng-required="true" close-text="Close" required ng-focus="vm.open($event,'opened2')" />


                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.open($event,'opened2')">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </p>

                </div>
        </ng-form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide more of the related code in the question rather than just a link to it?

Comment: i've tried to include code but having difficulties... can you see the plunkr?

Comment: Your `Close` button doesn't work in IE 11 either

Comment: In IE there is a constant Unspecified error from `editor.js`. coming from the plunkr while viewing your code only.

Comment: hmmmmm im perplexed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is indeed caused by the `ng-focus`. When you select a date, it focus' back in the field and re-opens the dialog (which looks like the dialog doesn't close)

The solution is to use `ng-click` instead -- it's better for two reasons. First, because it actually works, with the dialog closing after selection. Second, it's better usability because if the user has their focus on the input field already and clicks the field, it re-opens the datepicker. `ng-focus` doesn't show the datepicker in this case.

Some code:
`is-open="startDateOpen" ng-click="startDateOpen=true"`

Answer (score 1):

I my case, I added ng-click as follows:

```
 ng-click="startDateOpen=!startDateOpend"
```

also, I removed ng-focus to prevent from two events to affect 'startDateOpen'

```
ng-focus="startDateOpen=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

So for starters: the `alerts` array is not being used properly at all. There's a lot of code that does not function, or does not follow the example of how to use [alerts](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

You do not anywhere call anything to add to the `$scope.alerts` adding the code `<span>alert length: {{ alerts.length}}</span>` to the html shows the length is always zero.  Additionally the code to close is never called at all. Even if it was, as it sits, would not be able to close the pop-up since the reference to it isn't in the `$scope.alerts` array

Comment: yes im aware... forgot to take that out for the example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by this:

```
ng-focus="vm.open($event,'opened1')"
```

Comment: what if I need to open on focus?